# Assembly mix with C - what does this instruction means? CALL [EBX]my_pointer.my_function_address?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have two questions related to x86 inline assembly below:

1) What does `[ebx]my_pointer.my_char_array` do?
2) What does `call [ebx]my_pointer.my_function_address` do?

I'm using Windows 7 and Visual Studio. CPU is x86.

```
_declspec(naked) void my_c_function(my_struct* my_pointer)
{

_asm{
;normal prologue code here

mov     ebx, [ebp + 8];
lea     eax, [ebx]my_pointer.my_char_array;
push    eax;
call    [ebx]my_pointer.my_function_address;

;normal epilogue code here...
}
```

Comment: Those are just the addresses of elements within the my_struct structure pointed to by my_pointer, so here all that's happening is a call via a function pointer passing a string as a single parameter.

Comment: @Paul R . Do u mean that my_pointer.my_char_array address is loaded into eax register with this instruction "lea eax,[ebx]my_pointer.my_char_array"?

Comment: That's correct, then this address is pushed onto the stack as a function parameter, prior to calling the function pointed to by my_pointer->my_function_address.

Comment: @Paul R. Why I need to put [ebx] at the front of my_pointer.my_char_array? why I cannot do this "lea eax, my_pointer.my_char_array"? and can I use any registers besides "ebx" . sorry I'm new to assembly. thnx

Comment: `ebx` is initially loaded with `my_pointer`, so that it points at the start of the struct. The elements of the struct are referenced as offsets from this base address.

Comment: `[ebx]offset` is the same as `[ebx + offset]`